# Solr facet pivot sort by count ascending?

Tags: solr, faceted-search

When faceting on two fields, say `fieldone, fieldtwo`, I'll get a response like this:

```
"facet_pivot":{
  "fieldone,fieldtwo":[{
      "field":"fieldone",
      "value":"453dd082-3fb5-1de8-2c2a-d08b0b8789a6",
      "count":576,
      "pivot":[{
          "field":"fieldtwo",
          "value":2,
          "count":575},
        {
          "field":"fieldtwo",
          "value":1,
          "count":1}]},
    {
      "field":"fieldone",
      "value":"a4970fde-c960-45ea-444f-fb1fe06ece2e",
      "count":375,
      "pivot":[{
          "field":"fieldtwo",
          "value":2,
          "count":374},
        {
          "field":"fieldtwo",
          "value":1,
          "count":1}]},
```

Note the counts before each pivot (`576`, `375`). Can I sort these results ascending instead, so that the pivot with count `375` is the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way using the json api; I could not get the correct results with normal query parameters even though they seemed very similar.

Here is the `json.facet` parameter that worked (note the `count:asc` - I tried this with normal parameters as well but it didn't work).

```
json.facet={f1:{type:terms,field:fieldone,sort:{count:asc},facet:{f2:{type:terms,field:fieldtwo}}}}
```

This blog post helped me https://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2016/10/inside-the-apache-solr-json-facet-api/